# Is there a possibility to give a marker an id or class within the "properties" of the marker and to use this ID/Class in a click function afterwards?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

```
map.on('load', function () {

map.addSource("markers", {

"type": "geojson",

        "data": {
             "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [4.869929, 50.465887]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "marker-symbol": "pin-2"
                    "id or class?": ".."
                }
           }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote on your code is good, you can add any properties in the `properties` part.

Please refer to my example : http://codepen.io/poupi/pen/qZeXdK